# Laravel DB facade to use several DB

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-facade

Below is how to use Facade for search table data with pagination in Laravel.

```
DB::table('customers')->paginate(15);
```

but it can be use just a DB,

So how to use several DB in Facade sentence?

I wish to use DB as divide as read and write DB or direct access in single sentence.

Thank you in advenced.

Comment: You need to use **connection method** , `DB::connection('read')->table('customers')->paginate(15);` , `DB::connection('write')->table('customers')->paginate(15);`

For more details -> https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#using-multiple-database-connections

Comment: @Suresh Velusamy, Thank you.:) so if there several DB has different connection informations in user, password, etc... then how to write database connection setting?

Comment: You have to update your `phpunit.xml` with new testing environmental variables

<php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="DB_SLAVE_DATABASE" value="db1"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="database"/>
    </php>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to specify configuration for your databases in 
`.env`:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=172.17.0.1
DB_DATABASE=my_database
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password

DB_SLAVE_HOST=172.17.0.1
DB_SLAVE_DATABASE=my_database_slave
DB_SLAVE_USERNAME=username2
DB_SLAVE_PASSWORD=password2

DB_MASTER_HOST=172.17.0.1
DB_MASTER_DATABASE=my_database
DB_MASTER_USERNAME=username
DB_MASTER_PASSWORD=password
```

and

`project.dev/config/database.php`:

```
    'mysql_master' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_MASTER_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port'      => env('DB_MASTER_PORT', '3306'),
        'database'  => env('DB_MASTER_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_MASTER_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_MASTER_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
        'engine'    => null,
    ],
    'mysql_slave'        => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_SLAVE_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_SLAVE_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_SLAVE_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_SLAVE_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

Then you can use method `setConnection` like that:

```
public function getIndex(Product $product)
{
    $this->products = $product->setConnection('mysql_slave')
        ->where('id' '>' 20)
        ->get()
...
```